# Object seems wiped out after custom setter is called through Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to learn and practice **monitoring** an object like `Vue`. Variable `a` clearly shows `{name: 'old name'}` when printed out as soon as it's defined.

- I don't understand the part why `a` became `{}` after `Object.defineProperty`. Is this a must or is there a way `a` is still `{name: 'old name'}` after `Object.defineProperty`?
- I'm not sure what I've done in the `setter` is correct. Any suggestions on the `getter` and `setter`?

Thanks in advance.

```js
function def (obj, key) {
    let old_value = obj[key]; // Store old value
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return old_value; // Without this, console.log(a.name) returns undefined
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (old_value !== value) {
                // Only update the old_value if the new value is different
                console.log('value changed from "%s" to "%s"', old_value, value);
                old_value = value;
            } else {
                console.log('value not changed');
            }
        }
    });
}
var a = {name: 'old name'};

console.log(a); // {name: 'old name'}

// Use Object.defineProperty to define a custom setter to monitor the changes of key "name"
def(a, 'name');

console.log(a); // a became {}

a.name = 'new name'; // Set a new value
console.log(a.name); // "new name"
console.log(a); // Still {}
```

Comment: what js runtime are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Looks like it's working for me.

```js
function def (obj, key) {
    let old_value = obj[key]; // Store old value
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return old_value; // Without this, console.log(a.name) returns undefined
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (old_value !== value) {
                // Only update the old_value if the new value is different
                console.log('value changed from "%s" to "%s"', old_value, value);
                old_value = value;
            } else {
                console.log('value not changed');
            }
        }
    });
}
var a = {name: 'old name'};

console.log(a); // {name: 'old name'}

// Use Object.defineProperty to define a custom setter to monitor the changes of key "name"
def(a, 'name');

console.log(a); // a became {}

a.name = 'new name'; // Set a new value
console.log(a.name); // "new name"
console.log(a); // Still {}
```